# How to bind and trigger custom and native events in YUI?

Tags: javascript, events, yui, yui3

I'm trying to bind and trigger the following events using YUI, however so far none of the events seem to fire when I trigger them.

My code to bind:

```
        YUI().use('node-base', function(Y){
            Y.one(el).on(event,callback);
        });
```

My code to trigger:

```
        YUI().use('node-event-simulate', function(Y){
            Y.one(el).simulate(event);
        });
```

The `event` variable can be any of the following strings:

- `statechange` (custom event)
- `anchorchange` (custom event)
- `hashchange` (sometimes a native event, depends on browser features)
- `popstate` (sometimes a native event, depends on browser features)

The `el` variable is usually the `window` dom element, though may also be selectors and other dom elements.

Here is my current attempt to get it working in YUI:
http://jsfiddle.net/balupton/tFbum/

Here is what I want working in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/balupton/862Lg/

Thanks guys :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is currently impossible.